# Finding Minimum Value

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, maxima-minima

The question in the textbook is:

**if a,b,c are unit vectors, then $|a-b|^2+|b-c|^2+|c-a|^2$ does not exceed 'x'. Find x, where x is an integer.**

On solving we get this expression: $6-2(a.b + b.c + c.a)$

Now, I understand that we can use $|a+b+c|^2 >= 0$ to find the minimum value of the $(a.b + b.c + c.a)$ term which would give us the value for 'x'.

---

But I was wondering wether it would be possible to find the minimum value of the expanded version of the $(a.b + b.c + c.a)$ term?

$(a.b + b.c + c.a) = cosθ$<sub>1</sub> + cosθ<sub>2</sub> + cosθ<sub>3</sub>

Here's what I think, in a normal case where θ<sub>1</sub>, θ<sub>2</sub> and θ<sub>3</sub> would be independent, the minimum value would be -3 but the angles θ<sub>1</sub>, θ<sub>2</sub> and θ<sub>3</sub> are not really independent but bounded geometrically.

So, is it possible to find the minimum value of cosθ<sub>1</sub> + cosθ<sub>2</sub> + cosθ<sub>3</sub>?

**EDIT:** I'm in High School, forgot to mention that.

Comment: What about using Lagrange?

Comment: I don't know what that is...

Comment: Well for the record, the minimum value if 3/2

Comment: I guess you mean $-3/2$?

Comment: @amsmath oh yea, my bad.

Comment: Without loss of generality, you can assume that one vector is $(1,0)$ and the other two follow in counter clockwise order. Then If $\alpha$ is the angle between the first two and $\beta$ that between second and third, then the angle between the first and the third is $\alpha+\beta$, right? So, you have to minimize $\cos(\alpha)+\cos(\beta)+\cos(\alpha+\beta)$.

Comment: I believe that the fact that the dimensions aren't mentioned in the question means we can't apply that logic, as the angle between first and third might not necessarily be α+β in 3D.

Comment: You are right. However, you can always reduce the problem to at least $\mathbb R^3$. so, it is enough to consider $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: could you elaborate further by writing an answer if you wish? I don't really understand why you are using that notation.

Comment: Have you solved the problem in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @amsmath You mean 2D? I've solved the problem using vectors but I'm a bit weak on Trigonometry, so I could solve it that way, it's quite easy to do it the vector way.

Comment: Ok. By $\mathbb R^n$ I mean the space of vectors of the form $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. That is, $\mathbb R^n$ is just the space of vectors with $n$ entries which are real numbers. Now, when you are in $\mathbb R^n$ where $n > 3$, choose a minimum point $(a_0,b_0,c_0)$. Note that all three vectors are in $\mathbb R^n$. Now, the minimum value that you found is the same as that which you will find if you minimize your function on the space spanned by $a_0$, $b_0$, and $c_0$. But this space is at least $3$-dimensional. Hence, you have found the minimum value in $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Therefore, it is enough to consider the problem in $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$.